# Why isn't just_audio Flutter Android simulator playing any audio from a streaming service?

Tags: android, flutter, just-audio

The following code (snippet from the final app) works fine in iOS, and I don't get any errors when running it on Android Pixel 2 Simulator API 33.

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
...
...
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://renewfm.org/wp-content/themes/radiostation/showPlaying.php?device=web'),
      );

    //WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback( (_) async {
    //    await player.setUrl('https://renewfm.org/renewfm-stream.php');
    //    await player.play();
    //  }
    //);
    player.setUrl('https://renewfm.org/renewfm-stream.php');
    player.play();
  }
...
```

iOS starts playing it fine, with or without the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` code. The Debug output for Android seems to indicate it is trying to play:

```
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0(19617): bufferpool2 0x77d419df0818 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 213/218 (recycle/alloc) - 5/432 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0(19617): bufferpool2 0x77d419df0818 : 5(40960 size) total buffers - 1(8192 size) used buffers - 417/422 (recycle/alloc) - 5/840 (fetch/transfer)
...
```

But there's no volume. I have the simulator volume control up.

Here's my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:label="renewfm"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with a different emulator and it worked. Retried it with the API 33 and it worked. Go figure.